# $rename MongoDB field names using $regex in mongo shell?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, rename, updating

I've looked at other questions, but none that I've seen want to modify ***field*** names with a `$regex` in a mongo shell.  My attempts to use `db.collection.update` with `$rename` and a `$regex` have failed.

I have a collection with documents like this:

```json
{
    "_id" : "CWE-693",
    "Name" : "Protection Mechanism Failure",
    "Description" : "The product does not use or incorrectly uses a protection mechanism that provides sufficient defense against directed attacks against the product.",
    "Modes_Of_Introduction" : [
        "Architecture and Design",
        "Implementation",
        "Operation"
    ],
    "Common_Consequences" : [
        "Bypass Protection Mechanism"
    ]
}
```

I'd like to rename all of the field names (other than "_id") to eliminate the underscores ("_") so the document instead looks like this:

```json
{
    "_id" : "CWE-693",
    "Name" : "Protection Mechanism Failure",
    "Description" : "The product does not use or incorrectly uses a protection mechanism that provides sufficient defense against directed attacks against the product.",
    "ModesOfIntroduction" : [
        "Architecture and Design",
        "Implementation",
        "Operation"
    ],
    "CommonConsequences" : [
        "Bypass Protection Mechanism"
    ]
}
```

Is this possible with `db.collection.update`, with `$rename` and a `$regex`?  Are there other mongo shell programmatic ways to achieve this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Well, I guess that's the answer.  Write it here as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename) can only be used with plain strings, not regexes.

So you'd have to write code to read a representative doc, iterate over the field names and assemble a `$rename` operation to execute.